# Decimal keypad does not work properly in Ionic

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I am developing a calculator using Ionic.

Here is my code:

```html
 <input type="tel" placeholder="$0.00"  step="0.01" ng-model="model_income"/>
```

My problem is some devices doesn't have decimal points. Is there an alternative way to do that?

Comment: Have you tried using `type="number"`?

Comment: yes i used it work for it but i want to go with type="tel".Do you know any virtual plugin for that ..?

Comment: Why do you want to go with `type="tel"`, if the input is a decimal number?

Comment: i want to keep text  ass well Ex: i need to retrieve currency type inside that.

Comment: i am using angular currency filter

Comment: Could you explain further about wanting the retrieve the currency type? Can the user change the currency type? How are you retrieving it? Finally, with the `type="tel"`, you lose the placeholder once ANY input is entered, as with any `input` element. Is this still suitable for your purposes?

Comment: <input type="tel" placeholder="$0.00"  step="0.01" ng-model="model_income"   format="currency" ng-change="calculateTax(model_income)" select-on-click/>  here is full code

Comment: format="currency" is main purpose not a placeholder